# In Python PyQt6, Why is my QTreeView displaying white icons instead of folder icons from QStandardItemModel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qtreeview, pyqt6, qstandarditemmodel

I am attempting to add a folder icon for the folder items in my directory, along with the icons for the associated file type.

```
iconProvider = QFileIconProvider()

        for item in os.listdir(path):
            QItem = QStandardItem(item)
            file_item_icon = iconProvider.icon(QFileInfo(item))
            QItem.setIcon(file_item_icon)
            root_item.appendRow(QItem)
```

QTreeView Where folders show up with a White Icon

[image: QTreeView Where folders show up with a White Icon]

I have tried using the QFileSystemModel which does correctly show the icons, However, I need the control the QStandardItemModel offers...

QTreeView where icons are working

[image: QTreeView where icons are working]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the path used to construct the QFileInfo instance is not absolute, it can only use relative paths. As the [documentation explains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfileinfo.html#details):

> A QFileInfo can point to a file with either a relative or an absolute file path. Absolute file paths begin with the directory separator "/" (or with a drive specification on Windows). Relative file names begin with a directory name or a file name and specify a path **relative to the current working directory**.

<sup>[emphasis mine]</sup>

[`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) returns only the *names*:

> Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by path.

This means that QFileInfo will only have a "relative" name of each entry based on the *working directory*.

This is clearly an issue in your case:

- since you're probably using a path that is not directly relative to the working directory, it will be an invalid path, so the icon provider will use the default (usually, "new document") icon;
- coincidentally, if the path returned by `os.listdir()` coincides with an existing name of the working directory, it could even provide the *wrong* icon: suppose you have a `something.doc` file in the working dir and the name returned by `os.listdir()` also is `something.doc`, it will have the icon of the former file, even if the latter is actually a directory;

So, the solution is to use absolute paths *or* the proper icon type.

For simple cases (when the icon type is known), you can use the [`icon(IconType)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractfileiconprovider.html#icon) override using the provided enum. For instance, if you *do* know that the path refers to a directory (i.e. `os.path.isdir()`):

```
file_item_icon = iconProvider.icon(iconProvider.IconType.Folder)
```

Otherwise, you should use the full path, so that QFileInfo will use the *real* file reference:

```py
baseDir = QDir(path)
for fileName in os.listdir(path):
    info = QFileInfo(baseDir.absoluteFilePath(fileName))
    icon = iconProvider.icon(info)
    root_item.appendRow(QStandardItem(icon, fileName))
```